# Help identifying light lens

Tags: tail-lights

Found this near our mailbox that someone destroyed. Any help identifying the make and model of the vehicle this fits would be greatly appreciated.[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that looks like a light lens to me, but maybe someone here can identify it. I think the chances of that are slim though, unfortunately.

Comment: I have another pic, I just have to figure out where to upload it

Comment: Uploaded a new pic. I think it looks like either a piece of tail light or maybe the side of a headlight

Comment: Keep it in your pocket and find a large car park with many cars... You might find one that has that type of design on the lens.

Comment: Maybe walk around the neighborhood (if most people park on the street instead of in the garage) and look for a car with fresh damage on the right front.